# Find the source that fired a query

Tags: sql-server

*This is a hypothetical question - the problem listed below is entirely fictional, but I believe if anyone has an answer it could prove useful for future reference.*

We have a situation wherein multiple systems all populate the same data table on our SQL Server. One of these systems seems to be populating the table incorrectly, albeit in a consistent pattern (leading me to believe it is only a bug in a single system, not multiple) These are majoritively third-party systems and **we do not have access to modify or view their source code, nor alter their functionality.** We want to file a bug report with the culprit system's developer, but we don't know which one it is as the systems leave no identifiable trace on the table - those in charge before me, when the database was new and only occasionally used by a single system, believed that a single timestamp field was an adequate audit, and this has never been reconsidered.

Our solution has to be entirely SQL-based. Our thought was to write a trigger on the table, and somehow pull through the source of the query - ie, where it came from - but we don't know how, or even if that's possible.

*There are some clear solutions to this - for eg contact all the developers to update their software to populate a new `software_ID` field, and then use the new information to identify the faulty system later (and save my fictional self similar headaches later) - but I'm particularly interested to know if there's anything that could be done purely in-house on SQL Server (or another clever solution) with the restrictions noted.*

Comment: Are all the third-party systems connecting to the db using the same connection string? Specifically, are they using the same login?

Answer (score 3):

you can use functions:

```
select HOST_NAME(), APP_NAME()
```

So you will know the computer and application that caused the changes..

And you can modify application connection string to add custom Application name, for example:

```
„Data Source=SQLServerExpress;Initial Catalog=TestDB;
Integrated Security=True; Application Name=MyProgramm”
```

Comment: +1 for the first part, but as highlighted in my question, modifying the application (to change its conection string) is out-of-bounds.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a copy of the table in question with one additional `nvarchar` field to hold the *identifier*.

Then create a trigger for insert (and maybe update) on the table, and in the trigger insert the same rows to the copy, adding in an identifier. The identifier could be for instance the login name on the connection:

```
insert into tableCopy select SUSER_SNAME(), inserted.* from inserted
```

or maybe a client IP:

```
declare @clientIp varchar(255);

SELECT clientIp = client_net_address
FROM sys.dm_exec_connections
WHERE Session_id = @@SPID

insert into tableCopy select @clientIp, inserted.* from inserted
```

or possibly something else that you could get from the *connection context* (for lack of a more precise term) that can identify the client application.

Make sure though that inserting into the table copy will under no circumstances cause errors. Primary keys and indexes should probably be dropped from the copy.

Answer (score 1):

Just an idea: create a trigger that save in a dedicated table the info obtained by `EXEC sp_who2` when suspicious value are stored in the table.

Maybe you can filter sp_who2 values by status RUNNABLE.

So, if multiple users share the same login, you can determine the exact moment in which the command is executed and start your research from this...