# Get application information at SQL Server level for auditing

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, audit-trail

I'm writing a SQL trigger on a table that will update an audit table upon any change to specific fields with details of old value, new value, changed by, and timestamp. That is moving along nicely.

I'm wondering if there is a way that I can write a trigger for auditing on a table in a similar fashion but I can also figure out what application executed the query on the database/table? When we write the connection string we have this **App** property:

```
...provider connection string=&quot;data source=STGPDBCLS;initial catalog=StagingDb;persist security info=True;user id=abc;password=123;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Connect Timeout=80;App=EntityFramework&quot...
```

Does that play a role?

**TL;DR**

How to get name of application/Source that executed a query on SQL Server

Comment: You can not track which query has changed the value. You can only track the old and new values of a table.

Comment: @Suraj, I'm aware of that already. I'm interested in knowing the source of query so I can somehow identify the application /server responsible for the CRUD

Comment: I'm looking at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17340282/find-the-source-that-fired-a-query