# SQL Server Temporal Table: can I record who changed what?

Tags: sql-server, temporal-tables

Is there any way to record on a temporal table the user that changed a record? Any workaround?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with this question. This is a common problem to solve when system-versioned table are used.

Comment: Request you to check this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17340282/find-the-source-that-fired-a-query and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59942330/get-application-information-at-sql-server-level-for-auditing?noredirect=1#comment106010655_59942330

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not - there is no predetermined mechanism. THis goes back that quite often the db - when following modern architecture - DOES NOT KNOW.

See, we live in a world where you use a server (multi tiered application) and a connection pool. So, there is generically ONE user account that connects to the database server (the "server" account) and makes all changes. So the logged in user will not give you any information. A user reference field in the database is the responsibility of the application.

So, the answer is no - there is no mechanism to automatically record the user making a change.